# CSS - Overlaying Divs

Tags: html, css

I'm sure this is a common question but I can't seem to find a straight forward Q-A for it.

Say I have the following structure - what CSS trick do i need to implement to get `itemB` to overlay on `itemA`:

```
<div id="parent">

   <div id="itemA">
      Lorem
   </div>

   <div id="itemB">
      Ipsum
   </div>

</div>
```

Comment: [like this?](https://jsfiddle.net/ycbmtjjj/)

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is [positioning](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp).

In css there is a property called "[position](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp)", and in this case you will need to set the position of itemB to be absolute. Absolute means that it will be positioned relative to the parent (note that you need to set position: relative; to the parent otherwise it won't work).

And then you can just set top|bottom|left|right: {number of pixels}px; to position it however you wish. The itemA will not affect itemB at all in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS to overlay itemB on itemA.

Both the div are marked as absolute so as to be placed at the same position on the page and to override the itemA div with itemB, itemB's z-index should be greater then itemA.

```
    #parent{
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      position: relative;
    }
    #itemA,
    #itemB{
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
    }
    #itemB{
      z-index: 10;
    }
```

Comment: Explain why it's working? And why you need both elements to be absolute? What does `z-index` means?

Answer (score 0):

Simply apply `position: relative/absolute` and than use `left/right/top/bottom` to move element.

`relative` - do not take element from normal DOM flow, keeping it's reserved space, means other elements *will* be effected by this element position.
`absolute` - take out element from DOM and do not reserve space for him, means other elements *will not* be effected by this element position.

Use `z-index` to move positioned element in `z` direction (up or down stack)

```css
#itemA {
  background-color: rgba(200, 200, 250, .7);
  position: relative;
  top: 30px;
}
#itemB {
  background-color: rgba(200, 250, 200, .7);
  z-index: 6
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">

  <div id="itemA">
    Lorem
  </div>

  <div id="itemB">
    Ipsum
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this style :

```
#itemB{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  opacity:0.5;
}
```